# What is the best way to share a layout for multiple HTML files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, layout, shared

I like how in MVC you can have a _layout file in a shared folder and multiple cshtml files can use it. Is there anything similar I can do using HTML5, PHP, or Javascript? If so what's the most efficient way.

Thanks :)

Thanks. Using php files for headers/footers is exactly what I was looking for! Very simple stuff :)

Comment: templateing? not really sure what your asking

Comment: What I do is require a `top.php` and a `bottom.php` at each PHP file and that way I get a basic template.

Comment: Use a Content-Managment-System (CMS) would be one Option. The other one would be to make several Files for the Menü/Header/Footer and mostlikely the HTML Head Area and include them

Comment: I am looking for a way to have a basic layout for my html files. Mostly so I can have the same <head> with all the required script src's for javascript & jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Basic Layout is

```
HeaderBar

CONTENT

FooterBar
```

You can make 2 Files

1. top.php:

   - Head Area with your Syles...
   - Start of the Body
2. bottom.php

   - Footer and Javascript

Then you can include both Files with

```
<?php include '/yourfolder/top.php'; ?>
```

It always makes sens to put the menu into an additional File, becouse otherwise you would Need to acess every singe site to Change entrys.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now. It's very simple, just what I was looking for.